# Any serious risk if Mint 17 thinks it is Ubuntu?

Tags: linux-mint, apt

Running Mint 17, just ran `apt-get upgrade` for the first time in a while, with 350MB download. It stops halfway to tell me `/etc/issue` is not the package maintainers versions. Ditto for `issue.net` and `lsb-release`, where the diff looks like:

```
-DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
-DISTRIB_RELEASE=17
-DISTRIB_CODENAME=qiana
-DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 17 Qiana"
+DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
+DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
+DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
+DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"
```

OK, I've said "no" to each of those three file updates (i.e. keep it as Mint). Now I'm just wondering if this is a symptom of a more serious problem? Could `apt-get` be corrupted? Is there some simple check I can do to tell myself everything is OK? Google, so far, tells me no-one else has this problem, which seems strange if it is a mess-up in Mint packaging.

Sorry, that is a bit of a wishy-washy question. I guess it boils down to: Is it fine to shrug and think nothing about those three files?

---

**UPDATE**

Here is the output of `apt-cache policy base-files`:

```
base-files:
  Installed: 7.2ubuntu5.2
  Candidate: 7.2ubuntu5.2
  Version table:
 *** 7.2ubuntu5.2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.2ubuntu5 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

However there are some mint packages still, here is `apt-cache policy | grep -i mint`:

```
 700 http://extra.linuxmint.com/ qiana/main i386 Packages
     release v=17,o=linuxmint,a=qiana,n=qiana,l=linuxmint,c=main
     origin extra.linuxmint.com
 700 http://extra.linuxmint.com/ qiana/main amd64 Packages
     release v=17,o=linuxmint,a=qiana,n=qiana,l=linuxmint,c=main
     origin extra.linuxmint.com
 700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ qiana/import i386 Packages
     release v=17,o=linuxmint,a=qiana,n=qiana,l=linuxmint,c=import
     origin packages.linuxmint.com
 700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ qiana/upstream i386 Packages
     release v=17,o=linuxmint,a=qiana,n=qiana,l=linuxmint,c=upstream
     origin packages.linuxmint.com
 700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ qiana/main i386 Packages
     release v=17,o=linuxmint,a=qiana,n=qiana,l=linuxmint,c=main
     origin packages.linuxmint.com
 700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ qiana/import amd64 Packages
     release v=17,o=linuxmint,a=qiana,n=qiana,l=linuxmint,c=import
     origin packages.linuxmint.com
 700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ qiana/upstream amd64 Packages
     release v=17,o=linuxmint,a=qiana,n=qiana,l=linuxmint,c=upstream
     origin packages.linuxmint.com
 700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ qiana/main amd64 Packages
     release v=17,o=linuxmint,a=qiana,n=qiana,l=linuxmint,c=main
     origin packages.linuxmint.com
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I've gathered from Mint's repositories, Mint 17 (Qiana) is based on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr), and instead of hosting everything themselves, Mint rely on the Ubuntu repositories to provide all the packages that haven't been modified by Mint. This includes `base-files`, which contains `/etc/issue` etc.; it seems that Mint installs the Ubuntu version of the package, then overwrites the affected files with its own versions without using a package.

Now Ubuntu have updated `base-files` for 14.04.2, and because Mint uses the Ubuntu repositories, that update gets picked up by Mint installations. And since `/etc/issue` and so on were modified without going through the packaging system, `dpkg` reckons that the user changed something and asks before overwriting the files.

So to answer your question, as [Anthon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/33055/anthon) says it's safe enough, if a bit unfortunate (Mint really should have its own version of `base-files`). You can either keep the Mint versions or use the Ubuntu versions; the only consequence in the latter case is that software which needs to determine what distribution it's running on will find Ubuntu rather than Mint, but Mint is similar enough to Ubuntu for that to have no real impact.

Answer (score 4):

On reboot, it gets it's Mint back.

"IIRC *mintsystem* & *ubuntu-system-adjustments* will take care of these files on the next boot anyway, filling them with the correct Mint info."

Ref: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=175398

Answer (score 3):

I got these messages several times the last 6-7 months and always selected "No" on them, without any problems.

The `/etc/issue` file is only used in the login message and/or message of the day, if at all, and not for deriving any other settings on the system.